# Linux - Periodically backup SSD to HDD dual drive setup

Tags: linux, backup, clone

For context, in my particular situation I have Ubuntu 16.04 running /home on a 1TB hard drive, and / is on a 128GB SSD.

I know I can use something like gparted to copy my partitions from the SSD to the HDD, but is there a way I could setup something to similar to a crony job to backup my SSD to a partition of the same size of the SSD or larger on the HDD without having to power down the machine (Maybe this could be done with dd)?

Comment: Have you considered software RAID (mdadm) with write-mostly? Instant backup, no cron. Write speed does take a hit, but reads are still SSD speed. Alternatively, if you are using LVM you could take snapshots of SSD part, then clone them - this means the filesystem would be consistent (but not clean) - which would be better then a raw dd.

Comment: @davidgo Should I do this setup again I may go that route, but what I'm looking for is a possible solution for an existing setup where it'd me more work than it's worth to start over with a RAID setup just for convenient backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dd is the tool you're looking for, if you want to backup all partition. The command is quite simple. The if device is your / partition (probably /dev/sda1), the of is your backup partition on the HDD (in my example /dev/sdb2):

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb2 bs=1M
```

Set there partitions you really have on your system!

However as you're doing that on live system, the backup can't be 100% trusted as the system may write there something when the backup runs and this information wouldn't get propagated to the backup partition. In 99% it doesn't matter and fsck should recover the filesystem just fine.

The other option can be rsync. And it should be also faster. But again, it's live filesystem...

Comment: After some further research on this and taking your suggestion into consideration, I ended up going with rsync, so I'll select this answer.

Comment: [This may happen](https://www.google.com/search?q=panorama+fail) when you take progressive image of something that can change its state.